# Add key-value to nested json error - Element implicitly has an 'any'

Tags: json, typescript

I have a nested json like so, which I cannot modify as it is part of some package

```
const myjson = {
    properties: {
        'firstname':'david'
    },
    class: 'primary'
}
```

I want to add another key value to `properties`, so that it looks like

```
const myjson = {
    properties: {
        'firstname':'david',
        'lastname' :'watson'
    },
    class: 'primary'
}
```

So I used the following

```
myjson.properties['lastname'] = 'watson';
```

This gives the error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"lastname"' can't be used to index type '{ firstname: string; }'.
  Property 'lastname' does not exist on type '{ firstname: string; }'.(7053)
```

I think I have to use `as keyof typeof` something like below which is wrong syntax and doesn't fix the error

```
myjson.properties['lastname' as typeof keyof myjson.properties] = 'watson';
```

Runnable code with the error can be seen here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwFYXDAvDA3gKBvmABwCcRCBTYqAS3IgC5s8CWByAM2uOjAEM5yreqwAmvAG7URrZvgC+AGlkxgAG14QGMViWpxexBDLk5EKcADoSZSjToBtVup79BMDTCgIKIdjADW5Ai+8MioYFakFFS0EAC6GNoA7rxQ4awA3DigkCCq5BaqIADmABRm4QCUGUA

**Edit#1:** I made a small error in the order of `typeof keyof` in the above statement. Now the error is gone. The correct statement is

```
myjson.properties['lastname' as keyof typeof myjson.properties] = 'watson';
```

Corrected code is here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=76&pln=7&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwFYXDAvDA3gKBvmABwCcRCBTYqAS3IgC5s8CWByAM2uOjAEM5yreqwAmvAG7URrZvgC+AGlkxgAG14QGMViWpxexBDLk5EKcADoSZSjToBtVup79BMDTADW5BCHYwoBAo-eGRUMCtSCipaCABdDG0Ad14ocNYAbhxQSBBVcgtVEABzAAozcIBKDKA

**Edit#2:** Found one more way to do this without the error

```
Object.assign(myjson.properties, {'lastname': 'watson'});
```

Comment: What keys can exist on `properties`? Any string or only `firstname` and `lastname`?

Comment: @Lesiak There are more keys that I need to add like `state` , `country`. Or did you mean the keys could be of another data type?

Answer (score 2):

The inferred type of `myjson` is

```ts
{
  properties: {
    firstname: string;
  };
  class: string;
}
```

You cannot add new properties to this type - you need to let TS compiler know that `properties` can accept additional keys.
You need to add an explicit type to `myjson`

**Option 1: Index signature**

Use [Index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) if you have:

- arbitrary property names
- all sharing same type

```ts
interface MyData {
  properties: {
    [key: string]: string
  },
  class: string
}

const myjson: MyData = {
    properties: {
        'firstname':'david'
    },
    class: 'primary'
}

myjson.properties.lastname = 'watson';
```

**Option 2: optional properties**

Use optional properties if you have:

- a few well-defined property names
- possibly with different types

```ts
interface MyData {
  properties: {
    firstname?: string,
    lastname?: string,
    age?: number
  },
  class: string
}

const myjson: MyData = {
    properties: {
        'firstname':'david'
    },
    class: 'primary'
}

myjson.properties.lastname = 'watson';
```

**Option 3: create new object**

```ts
const myjson: MyData = {
    properties: {
        'firstname':'david'
    },
    class: 'primary'
}

const newJson = {
    ...myjson,
    properties: {
        ...myjson.properties,
        lastname: 'watson'
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a small error in the statement to add an additional property and now the error is gone. There is no need to modify `myjson`. I have added the details in the edit.

Comment: @ontherocks your solution (`'lastname' as keyof typeof myjson.properties`) allows you to add the property to the object, but the compiler still believes that the type is not changed (thus `myjson.properties.lastname` is flagged as an error). If possible, I would try to avoid this kind of difference between compile-time interface and actual runtime type - added option 3 as another alternative.

Comment: `myjson.properties.lastname` will be flagged as an error because of the precise reason that you've mentioned (i.e. the compiler still believes that the type is not changed). Hence, we have to use `as keyof typeof` everywhere where we want to use `myjson.properties.lastname`, for e.g. `console.log(myjson.properties['lastname' as keyof typeof myjson.properties]);`

Comment: IMHO `myjson.properties['lastname' as keyof typeof myjson.properties]` is far from ideal